# SQL Exception: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I am running following query:

`my query = insert into tbl_name (ID,name, address,...)" +" values (?,?,?)`

then I am using query runner class to insert.

`myQueryRunnerObj.insert("my query",
                          result set handler obj,
                          generated id,
'my name',
'my address',...);`

After this I am getting following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression` and sometimes `invalid number of arguments expecting 11 given 10`

What could be the reason to get this exception?

Comment: It might be helpful to recreate the actual query but with dummy columns since the error clearly appears to be within syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname) VALUES (dept_seq.nextval, 1);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname)
 SELECT dept_seq.nextval, 2
   FROM dual;
```

Answer (score -2):

ORA-00936:  missing expression
Cause:  A required part of a clause or expression has been omitted. For example, a SELECT statement may have been entered without a list of columns or expressions or with an incomplete expression. This message is also issued in cases where a reserved word is misused, as in SELECT TABLE.
Action: Check the statement syntax and specify the missing component.

check [this](http://ora-00936.ora-code.com)